# Why is it giving me a "you sent the name undefined" error when I send my HTML form in electron to my express server?

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I've been using electron to create a desktop app and I've been having trouble sending the input form data to my express server as it gives me the "you sent the name undefined" error. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks! Here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
    res.send('You sent the name "' + req.query.name + '".');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});







<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/myaction" method="post">

 <input type="email" name="email" id="fremail" placeholder="your@email.com" required/>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Continue" />
 <br>
 </form>

 <br>
 <br>
 <br>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/myaction" method="post">
    <input class="inputNum" type="number" min="1000" max="9999" name="num1" id="num1" placeholder = "XXXX" required/>
  -
    <input class="inputNum" type="number" min="1000" max="9999" name="num2" id="num2" placeholder = "XXXX" required/>
  -
    <input class="inputNum" type="number" min="1000" max="9999" name="num3" id="num3" placeholder = "XXXX" required/>
  -
    <input class="inputNum" type="number" min="1000" max="9999"  name="num4" id="num4" placeholder = "XXXX" required/>
  <br />

   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```